# Open sublime-project file programmatically

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm currently writing a plugin for Sublime Text 3, which aims to offer the user a more flexible session management.

As it seems the [API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) doesn't offer a way to open a `.sublime-project` file. I'm obviously able to open files as usual - using `window.open_file` - but not to tell Sublime to open a specific project file.
It will just open it in a new tab, which isn't exactly what I was hoping for.

I'm able to access and set the *project_data* using `window.project_data` and `window.set_project_data`, but while there is a `window.project_file_name` method it has no counterpart.

This is problematic since the *project_data* often contains relative paths, which need to be interpreted relative to the `.sublime-project` files location. If I just dump the data as found into a new window (`set_project_data`), all relative paths will be interpreted as relative to *root* (at least on my Ubuntu system).

I can handle the relative paths myself and modify the `project_data` accordingly but that's hacky.

Is there any undocumented method or something I missed?

**EDIT:** [The plugin in question.](https://github.com/Zeeker/sublime-SessionManager)

Comment: This is just a blind guess, but do command line arguments help? That is, when you spawn a new Sublime process from your plugin, can you just provide it with the path to the project file as the first argument?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke While that would enable me to open a window associated with the project file, the plugin still has to load views into this windows. AFAIK there is no safe way of accessing the window I opened via the command line.

Comment: If you pass a project file to sublime on the command line it will open that project file, along with any views it previously had open. If you need to do something after its open you could always write that into another plugin that has plugin_loaded so that it is executed at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the file with suffix ':1' - meaning 'line number #1':
This works for me:

```
$ subl projectname.sublime-project:1
```

Comment: That might work via the command line, but I'm trying to open the file from a sublime plugin. I have to continue working with the window after I opened it, so using a `run_command(...)` approach doesn't seem feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Found a method to do this in a Sublime Plugin called ProjectManager. You'll find the code in this file...

https://github.com/randy3k/ProjectManager/blob/master/pm.py

```
# Code lifted from https://github.com/randy3k/ProjectManager/blob/master/pm.py
def subl(args=[]):
    # learnt from SideBarEnhancements
    executable_path = sublime.executable_path()

    if sublime.platform() == 'linux':
        subprocess.Popen([executable_path] + [args])
    if sublime.platform() == 'osx':
        app_path = executable_path[:executable_path.rfind(".app/") + 5]
        executable_path = app_path + "Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
        subprocess.Popen([executable_path] + args)
    if sublime.platform() == "windows":
        def fix_focus():
            window = sublime.active_window()
            view = window.active_view()
            window.run_command('focus_neighboring_group')
            window.focus_view(view)
        sublime.set_timeout(fix_focus, 300)

subl(project_file) # The something.sublime-project file.
```